# Find overlapping appointments using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, overlap

I have a table with appointments each having start_time and end_time. Is there an efficient way to find overlapping appointments using SQL Server?

Comment: Add sample data and expected output.

Comment: Kindly provide some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap

Comment: Sample Data (id,start_time,end_time):

Comment: Sample Data (id,start_time,end_time): 
1,8:00,9:00
2,9:00,10:00
3,12:00,13:00
4,12:30,13:30
5,13:10,13:20
6,14:00,15:00.

expected results: 3,4 and 4,5. Note that in the second pair one appointment is entirely within the start and end of the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple join:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( ID INT, ST TIME, ET TIME )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 1, '8:00', '9:00' ),
        ( 2, '9:00', '10:00' ),
        ( 3, '12:00', '13:00' ),
        ( 4, '12:30', '13:30' ),
        ( 5, '13:10', '13:20' ),
        ( 6, '14:00', '15:00' )


SELECT  t1.ID, t2.ID
FROM    @t t1
        JOIN @t t2 ON t1.ID < t2.ID 
                      AND (t1.ST > t2.ST
                      AND t1.ST < t2.ET
                      OR  t1.ET > t2.ST
                      AND t1.ET < t2.ET)
```

Output:

```
ID1 ID2
3   4
4   5
```

The idea here is to find lines when at least one edge of line is between the edges of other line:

```
   a--------------------b
c-------------d


   a--------------------b
              c-------------d


   a--------------------b
         c--------d
```

If `[cd]` overlaps `[ab]` at least `c` or `d` will be between `a` and `b`.

Comment: What when [cd] is larger than [ab] meaning c is before a and d is after b?

Comment: @user1480192, since it is a join on itself it will check both situations. That's why there is checking for duplicates. Imagine that you have [x1, x2] and [y1, y2] intervals in your table. Self join will check both sides: it will assign x1 to a, x2 to b, y1 to c, y2 to d. Then it will assign x1 to c, x2 to d, y1 to a y2 to b.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method to find any appointment that overlaps with the next appointment:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*, lead(start_time) over (order by start_time, id) as next_start_time
      from appointments a
     ) a
where next_start_time < end_time;
```

Comment: Forgot to mention using SQL Server 2008 which does not have lead.

Comment: It might still be more efficient to use `outer apply`, but you have already accepted another answer.